# Error running a Shiny App from URL on GitHub

Tags: r, github, shiny

I am trying to run a Shiny App from a Github repo and I get errors, whether with runUrl() or runGitHub().

The files of the Shiny App+the data were zipped using Winrar and stored with Git LFS. The folder is accessible here
[Here](https://github.com/OmaymaS/Climate-Change-1900-2014).

Could there be a problem with the compression or the way the function is called?

```
> runGitHub("Climate-Change-1900-2014","OmaymaS",subdir = "Shiny_ClimateChange.zip")
Downloading https://github.com/OmaymaS/Climate-Change-1900-2014/archive/master.tar.gz
Error in shinyAppDir(x) : 
  No Shiny application exists at the path "C:\Users\HPPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iYTig\shinyapp1d60867c6969/Climate-Change-1900-2014-master/Shiny_ClimateChange.zip"


> runGitHub("Climate-Change-1900-2014","OmaymaS",subdir = "Shiny_ClimateChange")
Downloading https://github.com/OmaymaS/Climate-Change-1900-2014/archive/master.tar.gz
Error in shinyAppDir(x) : 
  No Shiny application exists at the path "C:\Users\HPPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iYTig\shinyapp1d6085ebc2c8d/Climate-Change-1900-2014-master/Shiny_ClimateChange"

> runUrl("https://github.com/OmaymaS/Climate-Change-1900-2014/blob/master/Shiny_ClimateChange.zip",filetype = ".zip")
Downloading https://github.com/OmaymaS/Climate-Change-1900-2014/blob/master/Shiny_ClimateChange.zip
Error in utils::unzip(filePath, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:\Users\HPPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iYTig\shinyapp1d60876fc38be.zip' cannot be opened


sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] curl_0.9.7      devtools_1.11.1 shiny_0.13.2    broom_0.4.1     RMySQL_0.10.6   DBI_0.3.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5     magrittr_1.5    mnormt_1.5-4    xtable_1.8-2    lattice_0.20-31 R6_2.1.2       
 [7] stringr_1.0.0   plyr_1.8.4      dplyr_0.4.3     tools_3.2.1     parallel_3.2.1  grid_3.2.1     
[13] nlme_3.1-120    psych_1.6.4     withr_1.0.1     htmltools_0.3.5 yaml_2.1.13     assertthat_0.1 
[19] digest_0.6.9    tibble_1.0      reshape2_1.4.1  tidyr_0.5.1     rsconnect_0.4.3 memoise_1.0.0  
[25] mime_0.4        rmarkdown_0.9.2 stringi_1.1.1   jsonlite_0.9.21 httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: It looks like a relative path issue; Shiny is particular (to an extent) about where you put things. Try moving the CSV to somewhere you don't have to step up a level to access it.

Comment: I actually work with an Rds file in the zipped folder with ui.R and server.R. The CSV is relevant to the Rmd.